# How can PhantomJS communicate through RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, phantomjs

I am new to RabbitMQ. I work with PhantomJS and use JavaScript to do stuff. Now, I need to send some of my results to the RabbitMQ in order to read them using another script. I mean, I want PhantomJS to communicate with RabbitMQ. To send some messages and to read some messages from the queue. Is that possible? Is there anyway by which PhantomJS can communicate with RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS is just another browser. That's exactly what the [RabbitMQ Web-Stomp Plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html) is for. It is based on SockJS which provides a web socket connection between browser and server. If web sockets are not available there are cross-browser fallbacks. PhantomJS supports web sockets from version 2 onwards.

If you don't `open` a page in PhantomJS, then you need to run this with the `--local-to-remote-url-access=true` option. I assume that sockjs-0.3.js and stomp.js are in the scripts directory.

```js
page.injectJs('sockjs-0.3.js');
page.injectJs('stomp.js');
page.evaluate(function(){
    var ws = new SockJS('http://127.0.0.1:15674/stomp');
    window.client = Stomp.over(ws);
    ...
});
```

This has to run in the page context (inside of `page.evaluate()`). So that is why `client` is a global `window` property so that you can get a reference to the client with subsequent `page.evaluate()` calls. You can trigger calls from the page context to the outside by using `window.callPhantom()` and the [`page.onCallback`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html) event handler.

Comment: Thanks. If I got it correctly, I cannot connect PhantomJS 1.x to the RabbitMQ. Right? Also, your explanation is not clear to me. Is there any documentation on this so that I can use it?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but SockJS documentation says that if WebSockets is not available, it will fallback to other techniques. So it should work with PhantomJS 1.x. What exactly is not clear? How to use Web-Stomp in a browser (which is the first [link](http://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html) I provided) or how to handle the connection from the page context?

Comment: Thanks. The second one. How to handle the connection from the page context? I already have a script for my goal. Do i need to completely change it?